# Why is the order of an element in a cyclic group a factor of the order of the cyclic group it is in?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If *G* has an element *a* of order *k*, then the group generated by *a* consists of {*e, a, a^2, ..., a^(k-1)*} which are all distinct elements of the group generated by *a* whose orders are a factor of *k*.

I don't understand this. Am I supposed to use the division algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right. Clearly any element $b\in \langle a\rangle$, say $b=a^i$, is such that $b^k = (a^i)^k = (a^k)^i = e^i = e$, so that the order of any element of that group is at most $k$. Now, suppose that $b\in \langle a\rangle$ and that $b$ has order $r$. Then $r\le k$, so using the division algorithm, write $k = qr+d$ where $0\le d < r$. Now,
$$e = b^k = b^{qr+d} = (b^r)^q\cdot b^d = e\cdot b^d = b^d,$$
so that $b^d = e$. But $r$ is the smallest nonzero integer such that $b^r = e$; it follows that $d=0$ and thus $r\mid k$.

Comment: Thank you. This makes perfect sense.